# Doctrine Entity Manager Not Removing

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to remove entities from my database using Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine.

In my controller I have:

```
if ($product->hasValues()) {
    foreach ($product->getValues() as $productAttributeValue) {
        if ($productAttributeValue->getAttribute()->getAttributeType()->getAttributeTypeId() != 5) {  // NOT Multi Select
            $matchFound = FALSE;
            foreach ($formElements as $name => $element) {
                $matches = array();
                if (preg_match('#(\d+)$#', $name, $matches)) {

                    if ($productAttributeValue->getAttribute()->getAttributeId() == $matches[0]) {
                        $productAttributeValue = $this->addProductValue($element, $productAttributeValue, $element->getValue());

                        $entityManager->persist($productAttributeValue);
                        unset($formElements[$name]);
                        $matchFound = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!$matchFound) {
                $entityManager->remove($productAttributeValue);
            }
        } else { // Multi Select
            $entityManager->remove($productAttributeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

`$product->getValues()` returns a `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` and `$productAttributeValue` is a `ProductAttributeValues` entity.

When no match is found, `if (!$matchFound)`, the entity is removed. However, when I call flush on the entity manager the records remains in the database.

When I persist the entity the database is updated correctly.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Do you have a $em->flush() somewhere?

Comment: Yes I do $entityManager->flush();

Comment: I figured it out, I put a $entityManager->persist($product) after the above code.